# Rails 4.1 has_many.js error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've been using Rails 4 for a while now and thought I had gotten used to turbolinks and how they affect page loads and the rest of your javascript.  
I use the 'jquery-turbolinks' gem to make hooking into document ready easier for the rest of my javascript and have not have any problems with it until recently after upgrading to 4.1 where occasionally I get a javascript error from a file called has_many.js that ends up breaking all the other javascript on my site.  
It is an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`  and looking into the has_many.js file it appears to be a problem with the `init_sortable` function.  
This is a fairly new app I have been working on and I haven't even set up any has_many relationships yet so I'm unsure why this would even be firing.  
If anyone has encountered a similar problem I would greatly appreciate any help. For now I'll probably just revert back to rails 4 for this project and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This is likely coming from ActiveAdmin -- I'm experiencing the same error and it's rather obnoxious!

Comment: could you fix it? Because i am having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you have active admin installed it has some has_many javascript in it.

Remove the following line from your application.js and require files on an individual basis:

```
//= require_tree .
```

require_tree is importing active_admin.js